# jQuery Animation Help

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div id="container">

<div class="nameContainer">
    <p class="daniel">Daniel</p>
    <p class="james">James</p>
    <p class="david">David</p>
    <p class="morrison">Morrison</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    if (!Modernizr.csstransitions) {

        $('.daniel').hover(function() {
         $('.daniel').animate({
            opacity: 0.25,
          }, 1000, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
        });

    }

</script>
```

So this should make it so when you hover over the "Daniel" text, it should lower in opacity to 0.25. However, when using IE (because it doesn't support csstransitions, so I had to use modernizr and some jquery to get to work) it just crashes the whole of IE and refuses to do anything. Now if I change the jQuery code to this:

```
<div id="container">

<div class="nameContainer">
    <p class="daniel">Daniel</p>
    <p class="james">James</p>
    <p class="david">David</p>
    <p class="morrison">Morrison</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    if (!Modernizr.csstransitions) {

        $('.nameContainer').hover(function() {
         $('.nameContainer').animate({
            opacity: 0.25,
          }, 1000, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
        });

    }

</script>
```

It'll work perfectly.. All the text will change opacity. However this isn't what I want; I want it so when you hover over one word it changes opacity.

Here's a live demo: http://mozazdesign.co.cc/newlogo2/

Any help on this would be great.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the event for the `<p>` elements in the `<div>`, then animate the element that was hovered:

```
$('.nameContainer p').hover(function() {
     $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
      }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
});
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen. How does it crash? What versions? Can you show a demo?

Comment: You're right; I have no idea what's wrong.  Try removing the custom font.